# bash: git: command not found in MSYS

Tags: msys

I already have git in my computer and I can use it.

I installed msys and:

```
pacman -Syu
```

This upgraded many packages. When I try to git clone in msys terminal, I get this response:

```
bash: git: command not found
```

How can I use git in MSYS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found an answer:

```
pacman -S git
```

Now I can use git in my mysy terminal.

Comment: I usually do `yes | pacman -Syu git`, but your answer is fine too, I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded "Git for Windows" then that installs MSYS2 but it's different to the MSYS you installed. They would not know about each other. You can merge the to as this guy writes (number 3):
https://www.automationdojos.com/install-pacman-on-git-for-win-without-full-setup/

If you start fresh, the I would get MSYS2 first, then use pacman to install mingw64 toolchain and mingw64 version of git - which is what you get when you install "Git for Windows":
https://gist.github.com/piotrkundu/e7d94204dd3c48525b23c59fe5d23478

`pacman -S git` will get you the MSYS version of git which runs with POSIX emulation (potentially slower).